# How can I get the body of a SOAP MIME response?

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, mime

I cannot get the XML body from the following MIME encapsulated SOAP response message:

```
------=_Part_2569448_1112730193.1684247686615
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="application/soap+xml"

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Header/><env:Body><ns2:ListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/mailwebservice"><ns2:uniqueIds>600165434@example.com:12345@2</ns2:uniqueIds><ns2:uniqueIds>600165434@example.com:12345@2</ns2:uniqueIds></ns2:ListResponse></env:Body></env:Envelope>
------=_Part_2569448_1112730193.1684247686615--
```

I make a SOAP XML request via an axios post request with a "Content-Type": "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8" header. I get the above response back. I tried to get the body with the mailparser node library, but parsed.text does not return anything, only undefined.

**My code:**

```
const axios = require("axios");
const simpleParser = require("mailparser").simpleParser;

// My SOAP envelope
const xmls = `
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mail="http://www.example.com/mailwebservice">
        <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
            <mail:ListRequest>
                <mail:accountId>500165534</mail:accountId>
            </mail:ListRequest>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>`;

// Your username and password
const username = "[USERNAME]";
const password = "[PASSWORD]";

// Base64 encode the username and password
const base64Credentials = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`).toString(
  "base64"
);

axios
  .post(
    "https://example.com/mailwebservice/mtom/mailwebservice-mtom.wsdl",
    xmls,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8",
        Authorization: `Basic ${base64Credentials}`,
      },
    }
  )
  .then(async (response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    let parsed = await simpleParser(response.data);
    console.log(parsed.text); // Logs undefined
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```